# UPDATE query with SELECT MAX in ACCESS 2013

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the 2 tables below in Access 2013

```
**tbl_GroupInvoices**
CustomerName  |  CountryCode  |  Group  |  UsageRate  |  SelectedTier  |
------------  |  -----------  |  -----  |  ---------  |  ------------  |
CUST1         |  FR           |  GROUP1 |             |     0          |
CUST1         |  FR           |  GROUP2 |     8.40%   |     0          |
CUST1         |  FR           |  GROUP3 |    47.91%   |     0          |
CUST1         |  FR           |  GROUP4 |    89.53%   |     0          |
CUST1         |  FR           |  GROUP5 |    45.34%   |     0          |

tbl_GenericTiers
CustomerName  |  CountryCode  |  TierName  |  UsageRate
------------  |  -----------  |  --------  |  ---------  |
CUST1         |  FR           |  GROUP1    |  20         |
CUST1         |  FR           |  GROUP1    |  40         |
CUST1         |  FR           |  GROUP1    |  60         |
CUST1         |  FR           |  GROUP1    |  80         |
CUST1         |  FR           |  GROUP2    |  20         |
CUST1         |  FR           |  GROUP2    |  40         |
CUST1         |  FR           |  GROUP2    |  60         |
CUST1         |  FR           |  GROUP2    |  80         |
```

I need to determine the selected tier on table tbl_GroupInvoices from tbl_GenericTiers,
knowing that the Tier is selected by looking at the actual Usage Rate of the Group in tbl_GroupInvoices and selecting the tier
that contains the usage rate.

e.g.
If Usage Rate  = 45.6% 
and I have 2 tiers defined for the group:

- 1 at 40%
- 1 at 60%

I need to select the tier 40%

If the Usage Rate is 64.3% then I select the 60% tier.

My SQL query looks like this:

```
UPDATE tbl_GroupInvoices
SET tbl_GroupInvoices.SelectedTier = TmpTable.MaxUsageRate
FROM (
      SELECT MAX(tbl_GenericTiers.UsageRate) AS MaxUsageRate
      FROM tbl_GroupInvoices,  tbl_GenericTiers
      WHERE  tbl_GroupInvoices.CustomerName = tbl_GenericTiers.CustomerName
      AND tbl_GroupInvoices.CountryCode = tbl_GenericTiers.CountryCode
      AND tbl_GroupInvoices.[Group] = tbl_GenericTiers.TierName
      AND tbl_GroupInvoices.UsageRate >= tbl_GenericTiers.UsageRate) AS TmpTable
```

I keep getting the following error message:

```
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'TmpTable.MaxUsageRate
FROM (
      SELECT MAX(tbl_GenericTiers.UsageRate) AS MaxUsageRate
      FROM tbl_GroupInvoices,  tbl_GenericTiers
      WHERE  tbl_GroupInvoices.CustomerName = tbl_GenericTiers.CustomerName
      AND tbl_GroupInvoices.CountryCode = tbl_GenericTiers.CountryCode
      AND tbl_GroupInvoices.[Group] = tbl_GenericTiers.TierName
      AND tbl_GroupInvoices.UsageRate >= tbl_GenericTiers.UsageRate) AS TmpTable'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
UPDATE tbl_GroupInvoices
SET tbl_GroupInvoices.SelectedTier = (
      SELECT MAX(tbl_GenericTiers.UsageRate) AS MaxUsageRate
      FROM tbl_GroupInvoices,  tbl_GenericTiers
      WHERE  tbl_GroupInvoices.CustomerName = tbl_GenericTiers.CustomerName
      AND tbl_GroupInvoices.CountryCode = tbl_GenericTiers.CountryCode
      AND tbl_GroupInvoices.[Group] = tbl_GenericTiers.TierName
      AND tbl_GroupInvoices.UsageRate >=UsageRate);
```

What's different is that I didn't put the nested SELECT statement in the FROM. Instead I put it on the other side of the equals. I think this is correct because I found examples online of nested SELECT statements here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa217680(v=office.11).aspx. This was the example specifically:

```
SELECT Orders.CustomerID, Orders.OrderDate, 
    (SELECT MAX(OrderDate) 
     FROM Orders AS Orders1 
     WHERE Orders1.OrderDate < Orders.OrderDate 
     AND Orders1.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID) 
               AS PreviousOrderDate, 
[OrderDate]-[PreviousOrderDate] AS OrderInterval
FROM Orders
ORDER BY Orders.CustomerID, Orders.OrderDate DESC;
```

Following this structure, I was able to make your query save in my access database which means there's no syntax errors so it should work. It's just a matter of the results now and what you want the query to return.

Comment: Thanks a lot. it seems OK but I still get 'Operation must use an updateable query' message.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can't use an aggregate function in an UPDATE query, try using a domain aggregate instead (not fully tested):

```
UPDATE tbl_GroupInvoices GI INNER JOIN tbl_GenericTiers GT ON GI.CustomerName = GT.CustomerName AND
                                                              GI.CountryCode = GT.CountryCode AND
                                                              GI.[Group] = GT.TierName AND
                                                              GI.UsageRate = GT.UsageRate
SET     GI.SelectedTier = DMAX("UsageRate", "tbl_GenericTiers", "CustomerName = '" & GI.CustomerName & "' AND
                                                                CountryCode = '" & GI.CountryCode & "' AND 
                                                                TierName = '" & GI.[Group] & "'")
```

Edit:  The table joins are listed first before setting the value in Access - basically the query without the SELECT fields or FROM statement (write a normal select query, delete everything before FROM and change FROM to UPDATE).